# Android Studio is not rendering/showing sample data

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

I'm using **Android Studio 3.5**, no sample image/avatar or text is showing in my device, however it is showing in design editor, but not in real device or emulator, have a look at this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[0]" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="Programmer, Nerd,Leet"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView7" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="John Doe"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView7" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

`tools:*` is used only for Android Studio layout preview, it doesn't show anything when you run an app. It's mostly used to see preview layout while you're writing code in Android Studio.
You also might want to add some placeholder image to drawables folder
I'd suggest you to change the `ImageView` to

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView7"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
android:src="@drawable/placeholderIcon" />
```